# Does Exodus 22:28 call for child sacrifice?

Tags: hebrew, contradiction, exodus, sacrifice

In Genesis, we see a motif of first-born sons being overly aggressive and ambitious. [Kain](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+4:8) slays Abel out of a jealous wrath. Firstborn Esau and Jacob have a long-running rivalry that ends with [Jacob fleeing](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+27:42) in fear of his life. Jacob's fear of Esua is so great that [20 years](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+32:7) do not diminish it. Rueben attempts to usurp his father's authority by [sleeping with the concubines](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+35:21).

At other times, the slights on the firstborn are more subtle. When Jacob/Israel blesses the sons of Joseph, he intentionally [chooses the younger](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+48:15) to receive the blessing. Genesis even points out that this was unexpected and [displeased Joseph](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+48:17).

The theme culminates in the final plague of the Exodus when God slays [the first born of Egypt](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Exodus+12:29). Shortly thereafter, God gives the commands for how the people are to live in the Land. One of those commands is quite surprising in light of the rest of the Bible. Exodus chapter 22:28 (with leading and trailing context) is not ambiguous:

> You will not curse God, and a prince of your people, you will not smear. For your goods and your wine-pressings do not be late, your eldest son *offer* to me.
>   Thus you will do for your oxen and your sheep: seven days it will be with its mother, on the eighth day, *give to me*. And a holy people thou shalt be to me, and predated carcasses in the field you will not eat, you shalt throw it to the dogs.—Exodus 22:27-29 ([Wikiproject Wiki Bible](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_%28Wikisource%29/Exodus#Chapter_22), emphasis added)

The context makes "give to me" clear—it means *sacrifice*. Placed parallel with "offer," this is a call for child sacrifice. Although this interpretation is, of course, impossible in the context of the rest of the Bible. However, child sacrifice is documented in the religions of the Ancient Near East.

However, later on in Exodus, one reads:

> All that breaks opens a womb, and all your livestock remember, first birth a bull and a sheep. And first birth of donkeys you will redeem with a sheep, and if you will not redeem it, break its neck. All your firstborn sons, redeem, and they will not see my face devoid of these.—Exodus 34:19-20 ([Wikiproject Wiki Bible](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_%28Wikisource%29/Exodus#Chapter_34))

The call is to kill all that is firstborn of animals. The exceptions are donkeys, which one **may** redeem with a sheep, and sons which **must** be "redeemed." One can interpret this verse as saying that an animal sacrifice must be substituted for a human male.

Does Exodus 22:28 call for killing firstborn sons in ritual child sacrifice?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, but I believe the earliest versions of the religion demanded child sacrifice, with reforms that abolish this coming later. This removes the interpretation stretches regarding these two verses. Unfortunately, I can't support this with anything else, it is just a suspicion, based upon the odd nature of Genesis 22, and the firstborn sacrifice logic of Exodus.

Comment: There are certainly scholars who believe child sacrifice was an ancient Israeli practice. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_sacrifice#cite_note-6) and [an interview with Thom Stark](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/valerie-tarico/polytheism-and-human-sacr_b_777340.html).

Answer (score 14):

Offering the eldest, the firtsborn, the firstfruits, etc is all about putting God in the forefront of your life.

This is shown clearly in [1 Samuel 1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%201:11&version=NASB) where Hannah dedicates her firstborn son to the Lord in service:

> She made a vow and said, "O LORD of hosts, if You will indeed look on the affliction of Your maidservant and remember me, and not forget Your maidservant, but will give Your maidservant a son, then I will give him to the LORD all the days of his life, and a razor shall never come on his head."

This is evidenced in myriad other places throughout the Bible - where the firstborn was to be consecrated to the Lord for the *potential* of special service.

With regards to the comment made about the "firstborn sacrifice logic of Exodus" - the firstborn of Egypt were not "sacrificed": it was a punishment from God against the nation of Egypt, with a clear and simple means to avoiding the judgement (the blood on the lintel posts of the door which became known as the Passover to be celebrated in perpetuity throughout Israel's history until it is fulfilled in Christ).

Comment: This is a reasonable explanation +1 and I might accept--- but I am confused about the parallel with animal sacrifice in the two quoted verses. I am hoping there might be some other evidence relating to a previous child-sacrifice practice among the Hebrews.

Comment: child sacrifice is explicitly forbidden to the Hebrews - however, using the same word in differing contexts with different thrusts is quite common

Comment: yes, I know it is forbidden, but I am wondering if this is true before 7-8 th century BC. Perhaps the earlier J narrative required it. The banning of child sacrifice is in the strange E narrative of Isaac's attempted sacrifice, which seems to be so strange, with God calling for a sacrifice, and later saying no, that it might have been explicitly written to end the practice.

Comment: @RonMaimon - have you decided on an answer to this question which best fits what you were looking for?

Comment: I am not sure, I wasn't sure. There is a theme of the firstborn male being inferior (Kain/Esau/Judah) because overly-masculine, killing firstborns is a natural extension. I was looking for archeological exegesis--- showing the practice was absent before the first exile, or perhaps that it was present then banned during the first exile. I can't say Monica's interpretation is wrong, but your interpretation is not great--- Samuel is "given" to God (Heb:titen), while the firstborns are "redeemed" (Heb: tiphdeh ), which is different, and from context has connotation of a killing sacrifice.

Comment: Conflict of interest disclosure: I am firstborn.

Comment: Reuben was the firstborn, not Judah. Judah was actually 4th born, but his elder brothers all disqualified themselves for leadership. Reuben tried to usurp leadership from their father by sleeping with the concubines. Levi and Simeon massacred a city to avenge their sister.

Comment: @FrankLuke - nice spot on Ron's misnote of the firstbornness of Judah :)

Comment: @warren: it wasn't a misnote--- I meant Reuben. I was thinking of the story of Reuben sleeping with Jacob's concubine, the thing that makes him "unstable as water" and unsuitable for an inheritance. This is over-masculinity. The Judah was a brain-glitch, I know the stories.

Comment: @RonMaimon Regarding your comment that this answer is "not great," it looks like Warren's answer is comparing the consecration of Samuel to God with the sacrifice of the firstborn, and not with the redemption. It seems that he is comparing the redemption of the firstborn to the redemptive blood on the door during the Passover. This could perhaps be seen as evidence that a precedent for the redemption of the human firstborn existed before the commandment to sacrifice the firstborn was given, thus never actually requiring the death of a human child. Just a thought.

Comment: @TheLedge - your opinion of my answer is not even close to what I wrote. I corrected OP's eisegetical reading of his personal mistranslation of the Hebrew.

Comment: @warren I should have been more clear. The last bit of what I wrote is my own idea, simply inspired by thoughts that I had as I read what you wrote about the Passover. I did not mean to imply that it represented your meaning, but these comments have a limited character count, and I was at less than 50 left. But the first few things that I said I think are in line with what you said. If not, you could certainly clarify.

Comment: @warren Ron's comment contrasts Samuel being given to God with the firstborns being redeemed, as if refuting an association you made between the same two ideas. I was pointing out that this didn't look like the association you were making, and that instead you meant to associate Hannah's consecration of Samuel to the Lord with the idea of sacrifice. I drew this conclusion because you began the second sentence of your answer with "This is shown clearly in 1 Samuel 1," immediately following a statement explaining the purpose of sacrifice. If I'm wrong, I would love for you to clarify.

Comment: @TheLedge - you *seem* to be claiming (in agreement with OP) child sacrifice was prescribed in Israel by God. It ***clearly*** was not. OP's intentional misinterpretation of scripture is what I corrected in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without the proper knowledge/context, it appears so incredibly heinous and damning coming from the Heavenly Father as a clear command to sacrifice the first born human and animal. We see also see it in Exodus 13 (verses 12-16):

> “...you are to give over to the Lord the first offspring of every womb...in days to come when your son asks you, ‘what does this mean?’ say to him, with a mighty hand the Lord brought us out of Egypt, the land of slavery. When pharaoh refused to let us go, the Lord killed every firstborn in Egypt, both man and animal. This is why I sacrifice to the Lord the first male offspring of every womb and redeem each of my firstborn sons...”

We might deduce from the verses above that it was a way to “even the scales” because of the Lord killing the Egyptian babies and animals before Moses and Aaron led them out to the east/northeast. It demonstrates both sympathy and that God loves everyone (even the tyrannical at the time). Commanded child sacrifice among the Hebrews did not last for more than a few generations.

It’s also important to understand that the Hebrews were treated so unbelievably bad as slaves for a few hundred years after losing control of the food supply that Joseph son of Jacob was able to spearhead. The Israeli tribes were abused and became reckless, primitive spirits, often with very little education and self-control. This gives light to the appropriate nature of such a harsh and divisive temporary set of laws for the former slaves. Without the extreme consequences (and/or threat of them) for their actions, the judges’ laws would have had little to no effect.

Comment: What citations do you have for the conclusions you've drawn?